# how do I configure my Django app to use Dreamhost email?

Tags: django, email, settings, dreamhost

I created a django app that has a contact form where users can send an email to the company (The email configured in the APP)

I am getting "SERVER ERROR 500"

After reading this:
[django email settings on dreamhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082340/django-email-settings-on-dreamhost)

I tried the following format in my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.dreamhost.com' # I also tried pop.dreamhost.com / imap.dreamhost.com with their respective port numbers.
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True # I also tried EMAIL_USE_SSL
EMAIL_PORT = 587 # I also tried 25 and 465
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'EMAIL_PASSWORD' # also tried SERVER_PASSWORD
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_dreamhost_email' # Also tried admin@mydomain.com
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ''
SERVER_EMAIL = 'my_dreamhost_email' # also tried 'localhost' / 'admin@mydomain.com'
ADMINS = (('Jack Shedd', 'jack@example.com'),) # I used my details
```

PS: The app is working perfectly if I use gmail

What are the correct details to use?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts about that:

Change your settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

ADMIN_EMAIL = 'Dont reply <no-reply@your_dreamhost_email.com>'
SUPPORT_EMAIL = 'Dont reply <no-reply@your_dreamhost_email.com>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ADMIN_EMAIL
SERVER_EMAIL = ADMIN_EMAIL
```